# Better way to make the child element's border to overlap with parent's

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

I'm working on a project that demands this effect with the help of CSS:

[image]

Here is the description of what exactly I want to achieve:

The parent element (the `title`) has some padding and 2px border at the bottom. It also has a child (`title-inner`) which also has some padding and 2px border but with a different color, and it overlaps with the border of it's parent i.e. the `title`.

I'm using this markup structure:

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="title-inner">Widget title</div>
</div>
```

I know that it is doable with some adjustments in padding and margin properties of both of these elements, but the CSS I've written so far somewhat breaks on mobile or when the browser is resized (have a look a [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1ut1pyv/)).

Is there a better way to bring out this effect in CSS? Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/v1ut1pyv/3/

Comment: See my edited jsfiddle (num 3). Using absolute positioning of your title-inner did the trick in my case

Comment: @trainoasis It (your first edit) looks broken to me: http://goo.gl/1gwWXD

Comment: My answer below does what you want and keeps .title padding-bottom. Another user has already answered correctly as well with a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the coolest option is to use background, divs, and width.

[Animation Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/kmt3fcgc/)

using divs in stead of borders gives you a lot more control over the elements.

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="title-inner">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div id='line'>
        <div id='load'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after you use your divs you set the css

```
body {
    background: black;
    color: #ddd;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 2em;
}
.title-inner {
    padding: 17px;
}
#line {
    background-color:purple;
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
}
#load {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
    width:0%;
}
```

then you can manipulate the code using javascript.

```
   function loop() {
        $('#load').animate({
            width: "50%"
        }, 1600);
        $('#load').promise().done(function () {
            $(this).width(0);
            loop();
        });

    }
loop();
```

Comment: Hey @Neoaptt, thanks for the idea, I've edited the javascript a bit to fit in, but this is what I've been looking for. I have to agree that it is more flexible than any other CSS solution. Have a look at [my edit](http://jsfiddle.net/kmt3fcgc/2/).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of giving `padding` to both child and parent element, you'd better to give the padding to the child, and then add a negative `margin` to make the borders overlap each other.

```css
body {
    background: black;
    color: #ddd;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 2em;
}

.title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.title-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E64998;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    <span class="title-inner">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I've been using something similar to this in the project, but when the client resizes the browser window, the border breaks a bit. I have to fix it, and [trainoasis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28455894/4554949) fits better as the solution. Thanks for your effort and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use absolute positioning for your child element:

```
.title {
   border-bottom: 2px solid;
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom:20px;
   height: 20px;
}

.title-inner {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #E64998;
 }
```

Note that I added 50% width as in your picture example.

http://jsfiddle.net/v1ut1pyv/5/

Comment: It varies with the text inside the `title-inner`. I'll remove the width to make it look accordingly. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: [Neoaptt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28456301/4554949) seems more flexible and fits well in my requirement.